# Python code to automate desktop activities in windows

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, ui-automation

I want to automate desktop activities in Windows environment using Python. How it can be done? Some examples will also be helpful.

By desktop activities, I mean actions such as taking control over mouse and keyboard, access active windows properties, double-click on an icon on the desktop, minimize and maximize windows, enter data to an input popup window through keyboard, etc.

Comment: can you more specifically define "desktop activities" maybe some examples?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I control the keyboard and mouse with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946181/how-can-i-control-the-keyboard-and-mouse-with-python)

Comment: Here's a good summary: https://gist.github.com/diyan/f3c24653e63c24c99137

Comment: @Eloims: The question you reference is Mac/Linux, this one's Windows.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have a look at [SIKULI](https://launchpad.net/sikuli).

> Sikuli is a visual technology to automate and test graphical user
> interfaces (GUI) using images (screenshots).

SIKULI uses a very clever combination of taking screenshots, and embedding them into your python (it's [jython](http://www.jython.org/), actually) script.

---

Take screenshots:

[image]

and use them in your code:

[image]

Comment: Is project this still a thing? It's seems like the website is not longer available.

Comment: @Vahid I've updated the URL to the current location: https://launchpad.net/sikuli

Answer (score 10):

There are different ways of automating user interfaces in Windows that can be accessed via Python (using `ctypes` or some of the Python windows bindings):

1. Raw windows APIs -- `Get/SetCursorPos` for the mouse, HWND APIs like `GetFocus` and `GetForegroundWindow`
2. `AutoIt` -- an automation scripting language: [Calling AutoIt Functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301561/calling-autoit-functions-in-python)
3. Microsoft Active Accessibility (`MSAA`) / WinEvent -- an API for interrogating a UI through the accessibility APIs in Win95.
4. UI/Automation (`UIA`) -- a replacement for `MSAA` introduced in Vista (available for XP SP3 IIRC).

Automating a user interface to test it is a non-trivial task. There are a lot of gotchas that can trip you up.

I would suggest testing your automation framework in an automated way so you can verify that it works on the platforms you are testing (to identify failures in the automation `API` vs failures in the application).

Another consideration is how to deal with localization. Note also that the names for Minimize/Maximize/... are localized as well, and can be in a different language to the application (system vs. user locale)!

In pseudo-code, an `MSAA` program to minimize an application would look something like:

```
window = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(FindWindow("My Window"))
titlebar = [x for x in window.AccessibleChildren if x.accRole == TitleBar]
minimize = [x for x in titlebar[0].AccessibleChildren if x.Name == "Minimize"]
if len(minimize) != 0: # may already be minimized
    mimimize[0].accDoDefaultAction()
```

`MSAA` accessible items are stored as `(object: IAccessible, childId: int)` pairs. Care is needed here to get the calls correct (e.g. `get_accChildCount` only uses the `IAccessible`, so when `childId` is not 0 you must return 0 instead of calling `get_accChildCount`)!

`IAccessible` calls can return different error codes to indicate `"this object does not support this property"` -- e.g. `DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND` or `E_NOTIMPL`.

Be aware of the state of the window. If the window is maximized then minimized, restore will restore the window to its maximized state, so you need to restore it again to get it back to the normal/windowed state.

The `MSAA` and `UIA` APIs don't support right mouse button clicks, so you need to use a `Win32 API` to trigger it.

The `MSAA` model does not support treeview heirarchy information -- it displays it as a flat list. On the other hand, `UIA` will only enumerate elements that are visible so you will not be able to access elements in the `UIA` tree that are collapsed.

Answer (score 8):

You can try [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/).

It's a Windows GUI automation tool written in Python which is very simple to use. For example, you can do the following:

```
# to double click on an icon on the desktop
doubleclick("Recycle Bin")

# to maximize
click("Maximize")

# to input some text and press ENTER
write("Some text", into="Label of the text field")
press(ENTER)
```

The full list of available commands can be found [here](http://www.getautoma.com/docs).

*Disclaimer*: I'm one of Automa's developers.

Comment: Note: Current version (0.1.21 on PyPI) does not support Python 3.x and it has not been updated since 2011-05-24.

Comment: Are there any open source alternatives to this now?

Comment: I wonder whether this is answer or the promotion, The links are promotions only :(

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/) which provide a cross-platform Python way to perform GUI automation.

#### [Mouse Control](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html)

Here is a simple code to move the mouse to the middle of the screen:

```
import pyautogui
screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
pyautogui.moveTo(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2)
```

Related question: [Controlling mouse with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1181464/55075).

#### [Keyboard Control](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html)

Example:

```
pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!')                 # prints out "Hello world!" instantly
pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!', interval=0.25)  # prints out "Hello world!" with a quarter second delay after each character
```

#### [Message Box Functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msgbox.html)

It provides JavaScript-style message boxes.

And other.

---

For other suggestions, check: [Python GUI automation library for simulating user interaction in apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/42664/3474).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [BotCity Framework](https://github.com/botcity-dev/botcity-framework-core-python), an open-source RPA framework.

It's just python (no intermediary code, no jython, etc).

The example below executes SAP and logs in:

```
from botcity.core import DesktopBot
from botcity.maestro import AlertType, AutomationTaskFinishStatus, Column

class Bot(DesktopBot):
    def action(self, execution):
        self.execute("saplogon.exe")
        
        # #{image:"login"}
    
        if not self.find( "user", matching=0.97, waiting_time=10000):
            self.not_found("user")
        self.click_relative(172, 5)
        
        self.paste(user)
        self.tab()
        self.paste(pass)
        self.enter()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Bot.main()
```

As Sikuli, you have a tool to crop elements and have visual clues about the interface and UI elements. But in this case, it's a tool for editing .py files (not intermediary code) so you can use any python lib in your automation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ClointFusion](https://pypi.org/project/ClointFusion)

It's again a Python based RPA platform which internally makes use of [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) among other packages.

It has a friendly Browser based Drag & Drop BOT Builder: [DOST](http://dost.clointfusion.com)

You can find more than 100 easy to use functions:

1. 6 gui functions to take any input from user
2. 4 functions on Mouse Operations
3. 6 functions on Window Operations (works only in Windows OS)
4. 5 functions on Window Objects (works only in Windows OS)
5. 8 functions on Folder Operations
6. 28 functions on Excel Operations
7. 3 functions on Keyboard Operations
8. 5 functions on Screenscraping Operations
9. 11 functions on Browser Operations
10. 4 functions on Alert Messages
11. 3 functions on String Operations
12. Loads of miscellaneous functions related to emoji, capture photo, flash (pop-up) messages etc

*Disclaimer: I'm one of developers of ClointFusion*