# How to automate Flash using selenium and python?

Tags: python, flash, selenium-webdriver

How to automate flash as we cannot inspect the flash element ? Any leads will be appreciated.thanks

Comment: please go trough the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking the question

Comment: @AmitSingh well did you try (research) my suggestions? Any feedback or did I waste my time typing? This is why others down-vote your question. Move mouse over the "down" arrow and you'll see a pop-up saying _`"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"`_. They were correct isn't it? So it's not personal, they're just saying truth by votes.

Answer (score 0):

If Selenium doesn't work then try opening some browser window (*eg:* Google Chrome) and do the auto-click or auto-typing at the position of Flash object within the browser page.

Assuming your OS is Microsoft Windows...

For auto-click: 
[Python code to automate desktop activities in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825322/python-code-to-automate-desktop-activities-in-windows)

For auto-typing: 
[Interact with other programs using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14304493/2057709)

Else just try a different programming language (like ActionScript or C#) for this specific task.